# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting with Multiple Variables

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

Google spreadsheet conditional formatting: I want cell A1 to turn green if it is less than all of B1, C1 and D1.

I can get it to work if it is less than **one** of the other cells. How do I get it to work, where the condition is "if it is less than **all of** the other cells"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try clearing formatting from and selecting ColumnA and Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... **Custom formula is** and:

```
=A1<min(B1:D1)
```

Then select formatting of choice and <kbd>Done</kbd>.